# How to parse a JSON file to variables with the windows command line?

Tags: json, windows, command-line

I have this `JSON` file called `test.json` which says:

```
{
    "test":true,
    "limit": 
    {
        "min":0.5,
        "max":1.5
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to read this file in the Windows command line and have these objects parsed as variables.

**How would I do this?**

Comment: @Manish - Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use Windows Powershell as your command line, you can use the `ConvertFrom-JSON` cmdlet: http://powershelljson.codeplex.com/

Make sure your PowerShell version is above 3.0, as [ConvertFrom-JSON is available from that version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256706/running-powershell-script-in-c-sharp-converttojson-error).

If you use plain old CMD, you'll need an external tool for it. I like jq: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/. The tutorial uses `curl` for the examples, but you can just as easily use `echo` or read the JSON from a file.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use Powershell.

Comment: See the second part of my answer

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help me create variables. Am I missing something?

Comment: CMD variables are strings - the only way for them to hold complex hierarchical structures is if those structures are serialized. So, whenever you need a specific value from the JSON, you stream the variable through `jq` with a selector to select what you need.

Comment: We have the exact same reputations core btw :P

Comment: Quick question: how would I set a variable to the output of this? Say, I have limit.min, which outputs 0.5. How would I set it to a variable?

Comment: To answer my own question: `FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('type test.json ^| jq .limit.min') DO SET min=%%i`

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `type` here - you can use the file redirection operator `<`, and write `'jq .limit.min ^< test.json'`.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell example.
Create from file: `$js = Get-Content file.json | ConvertFrom-Json.`
Get subkey: `$js.key.subkey`

Comment: This should be the very best answer. Works for me, without installing anything.

Answer (score 0):

> *I'd like to be able to read this file in the Windows command line and have these objects parsed as variables.*

I'll interpret this as, you want to do:

```
SET min=0.5
SET max=1.5
```

I'd recommend the powerful tool [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) for this task.

**Basic command:**

```
xidel -s test.json -e "$json/limit/min" -e "$json/limit/max"
xidel -s test.json -e "$json/limit/(min,max)"
```

Whether you use 2 queries to return each value, or 1 query to return both values, both commands should return:

```
0.5
1.5
```

**Export with custom variable-names:**

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s test.json -e "min:=$json/limit/min" -e "max:=$json/limit/max" --output-format^=cmd') DO %A
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s test.json -e "$json/limit/(min:=min,max:=max)" --output-format^=cmd') DO %A
```

Both commands do:

```
SET min=0.5
SET max=1.5
```

**Export with key-names as variable-names:**

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s test.json -e "$json/(limit)() ! eval(x'{.}:=$json/limit/{.}')[0]" --output-format^=cmd') DO %A
```

> *To answer my own question: `FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('type test.json ^| jq .limit.min') DO SET min=%%i`*

If that's all you want, then...

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s test.json -e "$json/limit/min"') DO SET min=%A
```

or...

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s test.json -e "min:=$json/limit/min" --output-format^=cmd') DO %A
```

...is all you need.