# How to get just the number that appears in a line of a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have `file.txt` with a line that is just like this...

```
{ "success" : { "id" : "18" } }
```

How can I ignore all of that, and get just the number (18) and store it in a variable so I can use it?

Note, the number may change, it won't always be 18, and could be 1 to 3 digits.

I've been playing around with for but can't seem to get the tokens right cause the number is surrounded by quotes

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in file.txt) do (

)
```

Comment: Please see this answer as i feel it is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356220/how-to-parse-a-json-file-to-variables-with-the-windows-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40478716.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=4delims=:{}" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO SET /a var=%%~a
ECHO result=%var%
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q40478716.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The 4th token is assigned to `%%a` and the quotes removed by the `~`

Answer (score -2):

```
import re
number = re.findall(r'\d+', 'target_str')[0]
```